# RefreshControll data duplicate everytime do pull to refresh on ScrollView in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, uirefreshcontrol

**Description**
I implement a pull request using `RequestController` in React Native, every time I did pull to refresh the same data keep adding on in Flat list over and over. I implemented pull request not inside the Flat list but on the `ScrollView` which wrapped the `FlatList`.

**Actions**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button, Modal, Dimensions, ScrollView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, Image, Platform, TouchableNativeFeedback,FlatList, ImageBackground, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
class HomeScreen extends Component{
    state = {
        refreshing: false,
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.searchApi();
    }
    searchApi = async() => {
        const response = await axios.get('http://73udkYid.ngrok.io/api/v1/products',{
                headers: {
                    "x-auth-token":"eyJfaWQiOiI1ZdfjzZmM4YjIwYjBjZDQyMmJkNzUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MD"
                }
            }
        );
        this.setState({results: [...this.state.results, response.data]});
    }
    _onRefresh = () => {
        this.setState({refreshing: true});
        this.searchApi().then(() => {
          this.setState({refreshing: false});
        });
    }
    render(){
        let finalGames = [];
            this.state.results.forEach(obj => {
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
                finalGames.push(obj[key]);
            });
        });
        return (
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: 'white',}}
                refreshControl = {
                    <RefreshControl 
                        refreshing = { this.state.refreshing }
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                    />
                }
            >  
       
        <FlatList 
            data = { finalGames }
            keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem = { ({item: itemData}) => {
                if(itemData.empty == true){
                    return <View style = {[styles.item,styles.itemInvisible]}/>
                }
                return (
                    <View style = {{ flex: 1, margin: 4}}>
                    <View style = {styles.item}> 
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        onPress = {() => {
                            this.setState({ viewController: this.state.viewController++ })
                            this.props.navigation.navigate(
                                "ProductDetail", {
                                itemDataDetail: itemData,
                                businessname:this.props.navigation.state.params.businessname,
                                viewController: this.state.viewController,
                             })
                         }}>
                    <View>
                        <ImageBackground 
                            source={{ uri: itemData.photo }}
                            style={{ width:'100%',aspectRatio: 1, borderRadius: 15, borderWidth:1, borderColor:"#FAFAFA", overflow: 'hidden'}}>
                        </ImageBackground>
                        <View style = {{ margin: 5}}>
                        <Text style = {{color: '#2E2E2E', fontWeight:"bold"}} numberOfLines={1}>{itemData.item}</Text>
                        <Text style = {{color: '#2E2E2E', fontSize: 12, fontWeight:"normal", alignSelf: 'flex-start'}} numberOfLines={1}>Available now | Sold out</Text>
                        <Text style = {{color: 'white', fontSize: 18, fontWeight:"bold", backgroundColor:"#DE1F38", alignSelf: 'flex-start', paddingHorizontal: 10,paddingVertical:2,borderRadius: 8,overflow: 'hidden', marginTop: 5}} numberOfLines={1}>${itemData.price}</Text>
                    </View>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    </View>
            </ScrollView>
          );
    }}/> 
}
```

**Output** 
Data duplicated every time new pull refresh triggered

Comment: That makes sense ... cause you concat the new result to the current result-list stored in state `this.setState({results: [...this.state.results, response.data]});`

Comment: How to solve this @Hend El-Salhi

Comment: Im new to React Native can you tell me simple way to solve this issue?

Comment: Checkout the answer down below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I found a way. I just need to do this.
`this.setState({results: [response.data]});`

Answer (score 2):

*I assume your api-call returns the whole list of products*

This line concat api-response-data to the the list of products you already have in your component-state

```
this.setState({results: [...this.state.results, response.data]});
```

Try this instead...

```
this.setState({ results: response.data });
```

Comment: I tried that one already, I concat my results because their is a complicate promise return from my api-call that is why I want to place them in a new array. Are there any way I can place them in the new array without concatinate like I did previously ?

Comment: Could you console.log this `console.log(await response.data)` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, you already give me helpful hint. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your data instead of concatenating. Use:

```
this.setState({ results: response.data });
```

Also, you should use FlatList 'onRefresh' prop to implement refresh functionality instead of using an extra ScrollView on the parent.

Comment: I am aware of that, however the problem is my return from api-call is object which contain id and properties inside, so I have to remove the id using some steps under my render function, so I decide to put them in new array.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you already give me helpful hint. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well in that case there is a more better way. You should keep the key value pair as it is and generate a new array of ids and provide it to the FlatList. Then in renderItem you will get the key as item so you can simply access that object with that key from the main object like:

renderItem({item}) {
  const gameItem = this.state.results[item]
}

In this way your data will be more managed and easily accessible

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as you,
When I refreshed, the data was (data)+[(data)+(new_data)].

What happens here is that data is added to the array of this variable: results.
To prevent this you must first clear this variable: results.
So your code will look like this.

```
state = {
        refreshing: false,

        results : [],   
}
```

when API runs, this array will filled `results[{some_data},{some_data},{some_data},..]`,

While you refresh->
1st: The results will Empty,
2nd: reassign that array with newly added data from API.

```
_onRefresh = () => {
        this.setState({results: []});
        this.setState({refreshing: true});
        this.searchApi().then(() => {
          this.setState({refreshing: false});
        });
    }
```